# error because of ambiguity in template function declaration

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I am using some function templates in order to store data generically and per type.

I defined my  `template<class T> store()`  functions like below.

If I call the functions explicitly with the type `uint64_t`

```
store<uint64_t>( &p, my_value );
```

I receive a compile time error saying

```
    call of overloaded 'store(char**, uint64_t&)' is ambiguous
    candidates are: 
             void store(char**, T) [with T = long unsigned int]
             void store(char**, T2) [with T1 = long unsigned int, 
                                          T2 = long unsigned int]
```

If instead I write it without type I have no error ( compiler is inferring the type ).

```
   store( &p, my_value );
```

I noticed that the compiler is assuming a function having the second argument passed by reference, while my template declaration the second argument must be copied.
Do you know why this happened and what to do to solve this ambiguity or being more clear at type declaration?

Best Regards

AFG

```
template< class T >
inline void store( char** buffer, T data ){

    memcpy( *buffer, &data, sizeof( T ) );
    buffer += sizeof(T);
}


template< class T1, class T2 >
inline void store( char** buffer, T2 data ){    

    memcpy( *buffer, &data, sizeof( T1 ) );
    buffer += sizeof(T1);
}
```

Comment: `inline` and `buffer += sizeof(Txxx)` are both useless. For the latter, you may have wanted `*buffer += sizeof(Txxx)`.

Comment: Hi Matthieu! I didn't realize about this last nasty buf! Thanks for the fix! AFG

Answer (score 1):

Do not use overload functions. Change the name of second procedure:

```
template< class T >
inline void store( char** buffer, T data ){

    memcpy( *buffer, &data, sizeof( T ) );
    buffer += sizeof(T);
}


template< class T1, class T2 >
inline void store_special( char** buffer, T2 data ){    

    memcpy( *buffer, &data, sizeof( T1 ) );
    buffer += sizeof(T1);
}
```

Sample of using

```
store_special<uint64_t>( &p, my_value );
```

Comment: I think you mean "do not use overload templates". Function overloading is generally not frowned upon.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding this topic I found this column by Herb Sutter called "Why Not Specialize Function Templates" here  http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm  I think it will explain why + a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know which function implementation to take, since they both fit, and the details of what types are used for template classes are in the error message.

It looks like you can eliminate one method, this one:

```
template< class T >
inline void store( char** buffer, T data ){

    memcpy( *buffer, &data, sizeof( T ) );
    buffer += sizeof(T);
}
```